# Как сверстать вот такой блок?

Tags: html, css

Как можно сверстать вот такой блок?
Как видно из макета, при наведении на средний и правый блоки есть hover эффект.
Основная загвоздка для меня, как сделать строки одинаковой высоты во всех колонках. Желательно использовать только флексы. Начал вот так:

```css
.cards-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.card {
  width: calc((100% - 240px) / 2);
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 22px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.card:nth-child(2) {
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.card__item {
  border-top: 1px dashed #D0D0D0;
  padding: 24px 24px;
}

.card:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards-wrapper">
  <div class="card-names">
  
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__item"><h3>Lorem <br> ipsum dolor sit amet</h3></div>
    <div class="card__item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="card__item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="card__item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="card__item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="card__item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__item"><h3>Lorem <br> ipsum dolor sit amet</h3></div>
    <div class="card__item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </div>
    <div class="card__item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut tristique nulla mauris, eu tincidunt lorem ornare non. Aenean vel egestas eros. Aenean vel egestas eros.</div>
    <div class="card__item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="card__item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem</div>
    <div class="card__item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Макет блока]

Comment: тут надо js использовать ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Переделал решение ...
2. Добавил в родительские контейнеры 2 класса:  card1 и card2;

```js
let card1 = document.querySelector('.card1');
let card2 = document.querySelector('.card2');
let d;

for( let i = 0; i < card1.querySelectorAll('.card__item').length; i++ ){
  d = Math.max( card1.querySelectorAll('.card__item')[i].clientHeight, card2.querySelectorAll('.card__item')[i].clientHeight );
  if( d ){
    card1.querySelectorAll('.card__item')[i].style.height = d + 'px';
    card2.querySelectorAll('.card__item')[i].style.height = d + 'px';
  }
}
```

```css
.cards-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .card {
    width: calc((100% - 240px) / 2);
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 22px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 3px;
  }

  .card:nth-child(2) {
    margin-right: 50px;
  }

  .card__item {
    border-top: 1px dashed #D0D0D0;
    padding: 24px 24px;
  }

  .card:first-child {
    border-top: none;
  }
```

```html
<div class="cards-wrapper">
  <div class="card-names">
  
  </div>

  <div class="card card1">
    <div class="card__item"><h3>Lorem <br> ipsum dolor sit amet</h3></div>
    <div class="card__item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="card__item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="card__item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="card__item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="card__item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card card2">
    <div class="card__item"><h3>Lorem <br> ipsum dolor sit amet</h3></div>
    <div class="card__item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </div>
    <div class="card__item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut tristique nulla mauris, eu tincidunt lorem ornare non. Aenean vel egestas eros. Aenean vel egestas eros. sit amet, consectetur adipiscing sit amet, consectetur adipiscing sit amet, consectetur adipiscing sit amet, consectetur adipiscing sit amet, consectetur adipiscing sit amet, consectetur adipiscing sit amet, consectetur adipiscing sit amet, consectetur adipiscing sit amet, consectetur adipiscing sit amet, consectetur adipiscing</div>
    <div class="card__item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="card__item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem</div>
    <div class="card__item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Stranger in the Q скажите пожалуйста тут я правильно js написал ?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос ,то ты хочешь чтобы все строки имели одинаковую длинну. flex игнорирует стандартный width . Добиться желательной ширины или высоты возможно через max-width: ; и min-width: ;
Отпишись, если не помогло

Comment: Всмысле "игнорирует стандартный width"? Пруфы можно?